# Proving logical equivalence using substitution and transitive property

Tags: logic, substitution

I'm really stuck on a logical equivalance question using substitution and transitive property.
The question i'm trying to prove is;

$a \implies b \equiv \neg (a \land \neg b)$

and so far i have

$a \implies b \equiv$

\begin{align*}
    &\neg b \implies \neg a \\
 &\neg \neg a \implies \neg \neg b \\
 &b \lor ¬a \\
 &\neg a \land b \\
 &\neg(a \land \neg b)
\end{align*}

I'm just second guessing myself because I feel like all i'm doing is flipping the inverse of $a$ and $b$ and just declaring equivalence between them without having correct substitution or transitive property. I understand simpler examples where proving C if A implies B and B implies C etc, but this particular example is really confusing me, just wondering if anyone could help clear this up.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your 'derivation' the fourth line $\neg a \lor b$ is *not* equivalent to either the third line r the fifth line. So that's certainly not correct.

Also, while the first two steps are correct applications of Contraposition, going from $\neg \neg a \to \neg \neg b$ to $b \lor \neg a$ is not something I recognize as the application some elementary equivalence principle, because typically the equivalence dealing with the material implication is:

**Implication**

$P \rightarrow Q \Leftrightarrow \neg P \lor Q$

So, you get:

$$A \to B \overset{Implication}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg A \lor B \overset{Double \ Negatoin}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg A \lor \neg \neg B \overset{DeMorgan}{\Leftrightarrow}$$

$$\neg (A \land \neg B)$$

Comment: this is perfect, thank you so much for clarifying this it really stumped me